# Make a decision on [decision-tree]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[decision-tree](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/decision-tree) is an undefined meta tag with two questions, both of them closed.  Recommend deleting the tag.

Comment: Both questions have been closed for years. Flag them and ask for their deletion. When they're gone, the tag will also die.

Comment: @Robotnik - One is a waste of space.  The other is off-topic but had 3K views, 3 answers, a total of 5 upvotes, and a favorite flag, so a lot of people found it useful.  I don't want to delete it just to eliminate a tag.

Comment: It seems someone disagrees, there's now only one question remaining... and it isn't the 3k views one. Generally, if a question is off topic by current standards but was well received in the past, mods may make the decision to historic-lock them instead. (There's a lot more of these on Stack Overflow)

Comment: Status is completed-requires moderator to add the tag.

Comment: Yup. Ask them to add it in the moderator chat (link them here)